# Server 2012 - 4.5.Net Framework with 3.5 Framework concurrently running

Tags: c#, sql-server, frameworks

I would Like to know the Issues attached to the concurrent running of the .NET 4.5 and 3.5 Legacy framework running together concurrently.

Currently our team had to "Force" install the 3.5 .Net Framework as 4.5 Did not "Fully accommodate" our needs. The 2 Run perfectly together. How ever i want to play it safe so...
I have searched for many sources and obtained only advantages and reasons for wanting to run them together. I have found Beautiful tutorials which worked nicely to do so as well... Refer to here :

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-using-aspnet-35-and-aspnet-45#TOC301258515

Please Provide the following:

1. Issues i may run into with both running at the same time
2. Possible workarounds or methods of preventing the issue

Comment: "running at the same time" in what arena ? The same machine, process or city ? If you run the 4.5 CLR you can safely load any module (or assembly) built against any version prior to 4.5. If you have 2 separate processes running on the same machine then they won't interfere anymore than they would interfere if running on different PCs.

Comment: On the Same server in one room on 1 Machine. 3.5 and 4.5 Running Concurrently on server 2012. Thats what i want to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS you have 100% isolation between processes so you are absolutely safe in any concurrency issues.

All you need to do is to make sure that developers are not using version of .NET that’s newer than what you have on your server (for example devs use 4.5 and you have 3.5 running).

For each website and application in IIS you can set different application pool and you can set each application pool to use different version of .NET framework.

Answer (score 1):

You are safe to run 3.5 and 4.5 on the same server as they have a different CLR (runtime). 3.5 is using 2.0 runtime and 4.5 is using 4.0 runtime.

However, 4.5 overwrites 4.0 (supposedly bug fixes only but you may still run into problems).

4.5.1 overwrites 4.5 so make sure you have the same version installed on your development machine and on the server.

As stated in the article you mention, each application pool is using a different runtime. Configure each web site with the proper application pool.